# Emulator IMEI Number UNKNOWN

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio-2.3

I am using the emulator (with android version 7.1.1) from Android Virtual Device Management.
But for some reason, the IMEI number is **UNKNOWN** instead of **000000000000000**.

Does anyone of you experience the same thing? And have you found the solution to this issue?

Apart from that, is there a way to update the IMEI number?

P.S. Due to some licensing matter, I can't use GenyMotion.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me also, not sure why, but I close it and open it again with the Cool Boot Now option from the Android Virtual Device Manager and it works again.